# Knockout JS + JQuery UI - Issues with removing items from observable array after it has been re-ordered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have an observable array bound to a list that uses JQuery-ui for reordering with drag and drop. I also want to be able to remove items from the observable array. Everything seems to work fine until I try to remove an item that has already been re-ordered.

Consider the following JsFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/4mMfE/

Try dragging "Bear" to be the third item in the list and then remove him, it doesnt seem to work, yet you can remove the other ones.

Does anyone know how to get this to work as expected?

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the order of the viewModel's observable array not being in sync with the actual order of elements displayed on the page.

```
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that it has to do with the fact that the user is changing the order of items in the DOM and it is not being updated in the observableArray, so when you go to remove an item it can't be found.

What you need is a custom binding, that listens for the re-ordering events and updates the model accordingly. Conveniently this already exists for jQuery UI sortable: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Comment: This is a great library, exactly what I needed. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I think Knockout doesn't know how to update UI. It is removing elements from array.

Just change your removeItem function to this and see for yourself.

```
alert(self.items().slength);
self.items.remove(data);
alert(self.items().slength);
```